# Property of zero mean and unit variance random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, moment-generating-functions

Assume an arbitrary random variable $X$ is zero mean and unit variance, and $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. I have a guess, but I don't know whether it is correct,
\begin{align}
E \left[ X^{2n} \right] \le E \left[ Y^{2n} \right]
\end{align}
where $n \ge 1$. I check some random variables, and find they always satisfy the above inequality. Is this a general law? If not, is there any counter example?
Many thanks for any idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a random variable with finite mean and variance does not even need to have a finite fourth moment. Even if we require a finite fourth moment your conjecture does not hold, as shown by this counterexample:

Let $Z$ follow a [Student *t*-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student_t) with $\nu=5$. Then for $Y = \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} Z$ we have $E[Y]=0$, $E[Y^2]=1$, and $E[Y^4]=9$, whereas $E[X^4]=3$ for $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

In other words, $Y$ is a distribution with positive [excess kurtosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis#Excess_kurtosis).